# SwiftUI 4: How to solve AnyLayout 'init(_:)' error

Tags: swift, swiftui

I'm trying to change from one `Layout` to another when `Dynamic Type Size` changes. I've tried [Apple's example](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/anylayout) but compiler throws an error in **XCode 14 beta 3 (SwiftUI 4)** and couldn't find any info related to this.

I've also tried providing `Content` type and a content without success.

Did someone face this issue and managed to get it working?

##### Error:

`Initializer 'init(_:)' requires that 'VStack<Content>' conform to 'Layout'`

`Initializer 'init(_:)' requires that 'HStack<Content>' conform to 'Layout'`

[image]

##### Sample code:

```
struct DynamicLayoutExample: View {
    @Environment(\.dynamicTypeSize) var dynamicTypeSize

    var body: some View {
        let layout = dynamicTypeSize <= .medium ?
            AnyLayout(HStack()) : AnyLayout(VStack())

        layout {
            Text("First label")
            Text("Second label")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: WWDC demo - seems removed from production :D

Comment: works fine in Xcode 14 **beta1 !** and iOS16 – both in Preview and Simulator

Comment: This appears to be a regression that is now fixed in [iOS 16 beta 4](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/ios-ipados-release-notes/ios-ipados-16-release-notes): `Fixed: Both HStack and VStack no longer conform to Layout. (95611618)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue seems to be in both Xcode 14 Beta 3 and Beta 4. As a work around you can use `_HStackLayout()` and `_VStackLayout()` if you want to see it working.

There is a fantastic post on [objc.io](https://talk.objc.io/episodes/S01E308-the-layout-protocol) about the `Layout` protocol.

Obviously underscored functions shouldn't be pushed to production, but it will compile and run in Xcode 14 Beta 3 and Beta 4

Hopefully it this should be fixed in the final release.

Here is an example:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var enabled: Bool = false

    var body: some View {
        let layout = enabled ?
            AnyLayout(_HStackLayout()) : AnyLayout(_VStackLayout())

        layout {
            Text("First label")
            Text("Second label")
            Button("Toggle") {
                withAnimation {
                    enabled.toggle()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

**Tested on Xcode 14 Beta 3 and Beta 4 in iOS 16 simulator**